# Error when SVN update using PHP Script

Tags: php, svn, centos

Currently am working on setting up an development environment on centos in digital ocean, i had to work with SVN

Went through some tutorials and created repository in server. Also connect and uploaded files using Tortoise SVN from client machine successfully.

But when i try to update the changes using SVN update command, it works fine in server, but it shows following error for same command when i executed using PHP Script.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

This command works fine when i execute as su

```
svn --username uname --password pwd update /var/www/html/api --non-interactive 2>&1
```

causes following error when executing using php script

```
svn: E155004: Run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details) svn: E155004: Working copy '/var/www/html/api' locked svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database svn: E200031: Additional errors: svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
```

Comment: It seems that your PHP code runs under an account that lacks **write** access to hidden `.svn` directory at the root of the working copy.

Comment: @bahrep it runs under apache user. i did chown that user for that svn repository